# Download a PDF from within active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, activeadmin

As a Admin User in my application I can create a membership and attach a PDF file (using paperclip)

Within my view then I would like to be able to click a link to download that PDF document for that particular Membership

So Active Admin lets you create a custom action (and it will also generate a route for you)

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Membership do
   collection_action :download_pdf, method: :get do

   end
end
```

Within my view then I have

```
column 'File' do |f|
  link_to('Download Membership Form', download_pdf_admin_memberships_path)
end
```

Trying to put the pieces together I have

```
collection_action :download_pdf, method: :get do
  membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
  send_data(filename: "#{membership.file_file_name}.pdf",
            type: 'application/pdf'
           )
end

column 'File' do |f|
  link_to('Download Membership Form', download_pdf_admin_memberships_path(f))
end
```

At the moment this generates a url of  `http://localhost:3000/admin/memberships/download_pdf.60`

and when clicked I get the error

```
Couldn't find Membership with 'id'=
```

I am unsure on how to get the URL to construct correctly (pass through the id) and actually download the PDF?

Can I get the id of the membership through to the method?

Comment: try `link_to('Download Membership Form', download_pdf_admin_memberships_path(f, format: :pdf))`

Comment: doesnt work im afriad, see updated question , i get an error `Couldn't find Membership with 'id'=` how do i pass the id ?

Comment: I think like this: `link_to('Download Membership Form', download_pdf_admin_memberships_path(id: object.id, format: :pdf))`

Comment: ah i see, `id:` as we are looking for params id in the method call.. am i better to use send_data or send_file here ? i would have thought `send_file` ?

Comment: I think it should definitely be a `send_file` - `send_file membership.file.path`

Comment: that's great, thanks, only issue now is it downloads but wont open :) always something

Comment: so the downloaded file is not valid, right?

Comment: it downloads, but i cant open it after its downloaded, theres clearly data in there as the file is 128kb for example

Comment: Hm, not sure if I ever meet such problem..

Comment: let me know if you fould the solution and if my help was enough to post it as an answer

Comment: will do, thanks, you have helped a lot

Comment: actually all fine, you can post as answer, adobe was froze for some reason, typical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download the file you would be better of using [`send_file`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file):

```
send_file membership.file.path
```

Also modify your `link_to` for properly passing the object's id and also specify the `format: :pdf`:

```
link_to(
  'Download Membership Form',
  download_pdf_admin_memberships_path(id: object.id, format: :pdf)
)
```